# How to set all locale settings in Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, locale

A remote installed application has some encoding problems and on my local machine it is running fine.

What is the best way to "copy" my locales to the remote machine?

The locales on my personal machine are configured like this:

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: a user-specific locale (for one user) or generally for the whole system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easier way

1. Export all locales into a file

   `locale > import`
2. Open file and add export at the start of each line
3. Make it executable with the command `chmod ugo+rx import`
4. Copy to desired profile and execute `./import`

Comment: (a) "Copy to desired profile" -- does this mean to move the file to the home of the user (b) Is this a permanent solution?

Comment: And what would have been the shell script to write the import on each line ?

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried to do it from my computer to another ssh.

Answer (score 36):

You can set locale manually using `update-locale`:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

Read [the man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/update-locale.1.html) for more information.

Alternatively, you can manually change your system's locale entries by modifying the file `/etc/default/locale`.

For example, on a German system, to prevent system messages from being translated, you may use:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

**Note:** changes take effect only after a fresh login.

***Source:*** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: I think update-locale needs `sudo`. Personally I like your alternative solution, maybe you should make it a primary one. :)

Comment: updated it!! :)

Comment: "perl: warning: Setting locale failed." .. How to fix this ?

Comment: Run the following command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: @green I have the same issue and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` seems not setting local in /etc/default/locale. is there a way to apply update-locale for all ?

Answer (score 7):

There are some recommendations when configuring locales in remote machines

1. In Debian machines (remote machine), run the command (as root):

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

   On the first screen, select the desired locales. After that, you will be prompted to choose which is the default locale. Select "none" (reference: https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard).
2. Configure your ssh service (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) to accept environment variables from the client:
   uncomment the line:

   ```
   AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
   ```

Restart your ssh server, logoff and log back in and run the `locale` command. It must match your local machine's locale.

Comment: You said "On the first screen, select the desired locales", but I have tested on Ubuntu V14.04.2LTS and all the process is done automatically (`Generating locales...` ... and later `Generation complete.`) I get no selection screen.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez did you solve that?

Comment: Well, as for today, I am using v16.04 and, indeed, the "first screen" exists and I can select the desired locales. Maybe it was just 
a problem with v14.

Comment: Nice! Sorry about my **huge** delay. I didn't know how to use this tool that time and forgot about my account since then. Best regards.