# Where to put export LC_ALL=C?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, system-language

I ran it once, but my terminal native language went back to Finnish. I've tried unsuccessfully .bashrc and .profile.

I have followed the thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193251/how-to-set-all-locale-settings-in-ubuntu) about *How to set all locale settings in Ubuntu*.
I have also tried to setup English as locale:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

But output:

```
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_NAME="fi_FI.UTF-8" LC_TIME="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fi_FI.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 LC_MEASUREMENT="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fi_FI.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fi_FI.UTF-8" LC_TELEPHONE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
```

---

Where can you put `export LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: Do _not_ do this, unless you exactly know what you're doing (in which case probably you wouldn't ask this question). This locale has the ANSI (7-bit) charset rather than UTF-8, that is, anything other than plain English characters will be hopelessly broken. At the very least you should have `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8` (this is only available on Ubuntu and a few other distros, by far not on all Linuxes). Probably you're better off with going for `en_US.UTF-8` instead.

Comment: @egmont Please, make your comment an answer.

Comment: I did not answer your question :P

Comment: @egmont You did. It is the best answer here with explanation why so should be done as you explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either simply enter them by hand in each terminal you open, like the following:

```
LC_ALL=C
LANG=C
```

or you put it into .bashrc in the following way:

```
LC_ALL=C
LANG=C
export LC_ALL LANG
```

Comment: Which one is a permanent change?

Comment: First one does not work. I still see Finnish in `ls -la`.

Comment: Second thing gives the output `bash: export: 'LC_ALL,LANG': not a valid identifier` in terminal.

Comment: might as well put it into .profile but then it only gets set on reboot.

Comment: Does not work in profile, no error, but still `Finnish` in `ls -la`.

Comment: Did you do a reboot and check the second part again I had a `,` where no one had to be!?

Comment: No. Your 2nd set of commands do not also work with/without comma in Ubuntu 16.04. They put my GUI terminal time; so I could not write back for some time. It also took two times to restart the system to recover. I just fixed the thing in another TTY simply. I also tried all combinations of the two commands; but also `export LC_ALL; export LANG` Do they work in your system?

Comment: mhmmm, weird they work on my system , the second set  i mean, but another thought why not set the system itself on the gui side to use English language, and fin measurements?